# Compile error in xcode for service samples using alljoyn frameworks

Tags: ios, alljoyn

I'm trying to compile the alljoyn framework samples for iOS. After a long time searching and test I found the way to compile the core framework examples. But when I was tring to do it with notification service example. I couldn't figure out a way to make it work. I have set the absolute path for hearder serach path and library search path(it works perfectly when dealing with the core framework), but it seems that the service SKD which I downloaded from https://allseenalliance.org/framework/download (I tried both 14.06 and 14.12) is missing some library for the specific architecture, because under the sample project building settings I can find library path such as ../samples/alljoyn_services_cpp/build/$(CONFIGURATION)-$(PLATFORM_NAME)"
/../controlpanel/ios/samples/alljoyn_services_objc/build/$(CONFIGURATION)-$(PLATFORM_NAME)"
../services_common/ios/samples/alljoyn_services_objc/build/$(CONFIGURATION)-$(PLATFORM_NAME)"
../../services_common/ios/samples/alljoyn_services_cpp/build/$(CONFIGURATION)-$(PLATFORM_NAME)"
../alljoyn_services_objc/build/$(CONFIGURATION)-$(PLATFORM_NAME)"
../alljoyn_services_cpp/build/$(CONFIGURATION)-$(PLATFORM_NAME)"

Which I coulnd't figure out where I can find those directories (I can't find them with the framework I downloaded), so I just included two more path
alljoyn-ios/services/alljoyn-notification-14.12.00-rel/cpp/lib
alljoyn-ios/services/alljoyn-notification-14.12.00-rel/objc/lib
To match what I have in the framework.

When I compile the project it presents the following error:
[Xcode compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROZkE.png)
It seems like an architecture error but I compiled the openssl for armv7.
Anyone knows how to solve this?